# how to translate XML layout background attribute value into code?

Tags: android, view, attributes

I'm sure this is really easy, but one of those hard to find things for beginners!  Here's what I have in my layout XML file which I want to play around with programatically:

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="1dp" 
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" 
/>
```

And here is how far I've gotten with the code:

```
View ruler = new View(this);
ruler.setBackgroundDrawable(????); //or is it setBackgroundResource?
parent.addView(ruler, 
               new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
```

I'm stuck on how to translate "?android:attr/listDivider" into code and which setter on the View object I'm interested in. Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

Comment: You can try setBackgroundResource(android.R.attr.listDivider);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is said [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (in the "XML attributes" array) that android:background is equivalent to setBackgroundResource.

I guess you should try
.setBackgroundResource(android.R.attr.listDivider).